# How to reuse a string block in swagger

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-lambda, swagger-2.0

I am writing a swagger file for AWS API Gateway. I have to use a block of text for the integration for every single endpoint. This is how a single end-point is looking currently

```
'/products/{productId}':
  get:
    tags:
      - product
    summary: Get detailed information about a product
    consumes:
      - application/json
    produces:
      - application/json
    parameters:
      - name: productId
        in: path
        required: true
        type: string
    responses:
      '200':
        description: 200 response
        schema:
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/definitions/product'
      '404':
        description: product not found
        schema:
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/definitions/product'
    x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
      requestTemplates:
        application/json: >
          ##  See
          http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html

          ##  This template will pass through all parameters including path,
          querystring, header, stage variables, and context through to the
          integration endpoint via the body/payload

          #set($allParams = $input.params())

          {

          "body-json" : $input.json('$'),

          "params" : {

          #foreach($type in $allParams.keySet())
              #set($params = $allParams.get($type))
          "$type" : {
              #foreach($paramName in $params.keySet())
              "$paramName" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($params.get($paramName))"
                  #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
              #end
          }
              #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
          #end

          },

          "stage-variables" : {

          #foreach($key in $stageVariables.keySet())

          "$key" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($stageVariables.get($key))"
              #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
          #end

          },

          "context" : {
              "account-id" : "$context.identity.accountId",
              "api-id" : "$context.apiId",
              "api-key" : "$context.identity.apiKey",
              "authorizer-principal-id" : "$context.authorizer.principalId",
              "caller" : "$context.identity.caller",
              "cognito-authentication-provider" : "$context.identity.cognitoAuthenticationProvider",
              "cognito-authentication-type" : "$context.identity.cognitoAuthenticationType",
              "cognito-identity-id" : "$context.identity.cognitoIdentityId",
              "cognito-identity-pool-id" : "$context.identity.cognitoIdentityPoolId",
              "http-method" : "$context.httpMethod",
              "stage" : "$context.stage",
              "source-ip" : "$context.identity.sourceIp",
              "user" : "$context.identity.user",
              "user-agent" : "$context.identity.userAgent",
              "user-arn" : "$context.identity.userArn",
              "request-id" : "$context.requestId",
              "resource-id" : "$context.resourceId",
              "resource-path" : "$context.resourcePath"
              }
          }
      uri: >-
        arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:87126xxxxxxx:function:lambdatest_v3/invocations
      passthroughBehavior: never
      responses:
        default:
          statusCode: '200'
      httpMethod: POST
      type: aws
```

The part about x-amazon-apigateway-integration needs to be repeated as it is for every path. How can I **not** write it every-time. Is it possible to have a string definition to at least hold the part about `application/json`?

I tried creating a string definition but it didn't worked on aws import:

```
definitions:
  MyAPI:
    type: string
    default: >
        #Magic

        #set($allParams = $input.params())

        {

        "body-json" : $input.json('$'),

        "params" : {

        #foreach($type in $allParams.keySet())
            #set($params = $allParams.get($type))
        "$type" : {
            #foreach($paramName in $params.keySet())
            "$paramName" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($params.get($paramName))"
                #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
            #end
        }
            #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
        #end

        },

        "stage-variables" : {

        #foreach($key in $stageVariables.keySet())

        "$key" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($stageVariables.get($key))"
            #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
        #end

        },

        "context" : {
            "account-id" : "$context.identity.accountId",
            "api-id" : "$context.apiId",
            "api-key" : "$context.identity.apiKey",
            "authorizer-principal-id" : "$context.authorizer.principalId",
            "caller" : "$context.identity.caller",
            "cognito-authentication-provider" : "$context.identity.cognitoAuthenticationProvider",
            "cognito-authentication-type" : "$context.identity.cognitoAuthenticationType",
            "cognito-identity-id" : "$context.identity.cognitoIdentityId",
            "cognito-identity-pool-id" : "$context.identity.cognitoIdentityPoolId",
            "http-method" : "$context.httpMethod",
            "stage" : "$context.stage",
            "source-ip" : "$context.identity.sourceIp",
            "user" : "$context.identity.user",
            "user-agent" : "$context.identity.userAgent",
            "user-arn" : "$context.identity.userArn",
            "request-id" : "$context.requestId",
            "resource-id" : "$context.resourceId",
            "resource-path" : "$context.resourcePath"
            }
        }
```

and then in the path:

```
  x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
    requestTemplates:
      application/json: 
        $ref: '#/definitions/MyAPI'
    uri: >-
      arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:8712xxxxxxxx:function:lambdaTest_v3/invocations
    passthroughBehavior: never
    responses:
      default:
        statusCode: '200'
    httpMethod: POST
    type: aws
```

Comment: This may not answer your question directly, however are you aware that you can export this as JSON from an API Gateway stage?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do the reverse. I have a version controlled swagger file and I have a system to import the updates to swagger file to API gateway with `aws apigateway import-rest-api`. Since gateway integration will be repeated for all end-points, I do not want to repeat the same block again. I couldn't figure out how to do that. Now, I am adding the integration paragraph during deployment process.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry I misunderstood what you were doing. I have not used the import api methods yet, so I probably cannot help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://azimi.me/2015/07/16/split-swagger-into-smaller-files.html

> If you’re writing a Swagger API spec and it’s becoming too large, you
>   can split it into multiple files. Swagger supports JSON Reference
>   (draft) for using remote and local pieces of JSON to build up a
>   Swagger document.
>
> JSON Reference Overview
>
> JSON Reference uses the special key $ref to define a “reference” to a
>   piece of JSON. For example following JSON has a reference to
>   http://example.com/foo.json:

**Compiling the split json files**

Once you have json file split across multiple references, it is possible to compile them all together with `json-refs resolve` command.

```
json-refs resolve -I relative swagger-boot.json > docs/swagger/swaggerInternal.json
```

Comment: Do you know if this can work for AWS API Gateway as well? The specification above is written for Amazon AWS. Just curious looking to do the same thing. We don't want to do any of the string manipulation on our side if possible as it leaves an opening for errors.

Comment: It might not work because API Gateway takes a single file as input AFAIK. You can create a reference to another file containing the repeating block. As a build step, you can use `json-refs`. I have updated the answer to illustrate.